# Deriving 99th percentile in log-normal data using transformed normal distribution?

Tags: normality-assumption, quantiles, lognormal-distribution

My aim is to calculate the 99th percentile of the log-normally distributed data on the left-hand side. There are various approaches described to do this, e.g. ranking data and then selecting the value that is on 99%th percentile of the data.
I was however thinking of using the normal curve theory to accomplish this. As shown below:

1. Given the log-normal distribution on the left, transforming this data (`Y = log(x)`) would approximately result in the normally distributed data on the right.

[image: lognormal distribution]

2. Mathematically, `99th percentile = mean (u) + 2.33 SD (σ)` which can be calculated from the log-transformed normal distribution.

Is such approach valid? And if it is, when should I exponentiate these values? During the calculation or at the end?

E.g.: `exp(μ + σ × 2.33)` versus `exp(μ) + exp(σ) * 2.33)`.
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Find the 99th percentile of $Y$, then reverse the log transform `Y = log(x)` (i.e., exponentiate the 99th percentile of $Y$) to get the 99th percentile of $x$.

Comment: What @jbowman says applies to *any* strictly increasing transformation, not just the logarithm, and it is proven by applying the definition of a percentile.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot both. Any literature on why *NOT* to transform the single components of the distribution (e.g. exponentiate the mean and SD first, then find the 99th percentile)?

Comment: I urge you to consider that question ("why NOT") directly in relation to whuber's comment immediately above it ("apply the definition of a percentile") ... whereupon it should be immediately apparent that it doesn't work, that's why not.